# Is there a way to pass a variable to a callback function without wrapping it in another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope I'm asking this correctly.

I have the jQuery line:

```
$("main").load("link.html", runFunction);
```

and that works fine.  But now I wanted to pass a variable to the function `runFunction`, but doing

```
$("main").load("link.html", runFunction(myvar));
```

doesn't work because it's being called right away.  And I do know that I could do

```
$("main").load("link.html", function() {runFunction(myvar)});
```

But I was wondering if there was any other way to send the variable to the runFunction without that extra wrapper function.

Comment: Yes, there is a way, though you'd need even more code. Why not just use the wrapper?

Comment: There's `bind`, but generally the last snippet is the correct way to do it

Comment: The code you have above is about the simplest solution.

Answer (score 2):

Under the hood, creating a new function is inescapable, since the "bound" parameter you are passing in is tied to a certain scope, and the function you will be invoking will be invoked at a *different* scope. To achieve this, you need a closure, which you would create with an inline anonymous function.

That said, JavaScript makes this easier through the `Function.prototype.bind` call. Check out [`bind()` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

`bind` allows you to create *leading* bound parameters (i.e., you cannot use this to bind the *second* argument to a variable but not the first).

```
$("main").load("link.html", function() {runFunction(myvar)});
```

Becomes

```
$("main").load("link.html", runFunction.bind(window, myvar)});
```

Note that the first argument you pass to `bind` is the `thisArg`, which is the JavaScript Object which will be associated with the `this` argument in the body of the function.